# How can I combine two queries or search for different fields using MongoDB's Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

How can I combine two queries (lets say query1 and query2) to search a mongodb collection.

```
FindIterable<Document> docs = col.find(query);
```

The above code searches only one query. Or is there any other way of finding documents that satisfies different queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine predicates.

Using `Filters.and()`, for example ...

```
Bson queryOne = Filters.eq("name", "Bill");
Bson queryTwo = Filters.gt("age", 25);
Bson query = Filters.and(queryOne, queryTwo);
FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(query);
```

... will return the documents which match both `queryOne` **and** `queryTwo`.

Similarly, using `Filters.or()` ...

```
Bson queryOne = Filters.eq("name", "Bill");
Bson queryTwo = Filters.gt("age", 25);
Bson query = Filters.or(queryOne, queryTwo);
FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(query);
```

... will return the documents which match either `queryOne` **or** `queryTwo`.